# Linked list homemade class cryes about memory access troubles (C++)

Tags: c++, visual-studio, list

when building the project in Visual Studio 2013 the message:
Unhandled exception at 0x00CD5154 in prj.exe: 0xC0000005: Access violation writing location 0x00000004
Please help. It's actualy an example https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=3gZ7F31Mwi0 I write almost the same.

Header.h

```
#ifndef HEADER_H_
#define HEADER_H_

#include <iostream>
#include <string>
//#include <iostream>
//#include <vector>
typedef struct Node
{
    int data;
    Node* link;
}* NodePtr;

class List
{
public:
    List();
    ~List();
    int numberOfElements();
    NodePtr getPointer(const int node_number) const;
    void addNode(int data_);
    //NodePtr head;
private:


    NodePtr head;
    NodePtr curr;
    NodePtr temp;
    NodePtr start_index;

};

#endif // !HEADER_H_
```

Source.cpp

```
   #include "Header.h"    
    List::List()
    {
        head = NULL;
        curr = NULL;
        temp = NULL;//head_ptr = this->Nodes;
        start_index = NULL;
    }

    List::~List()
    {

    }
    int List::numberOfElements() 
    {
        size_t i = 0;
        temp = start_index;
        while (temp->link != NULL)
        {
            temp = temp->link;
            i++;
        }
        return i;
    }
    NodePtr List::getPointer(const int node_number) const
    {   
        NodePtr counter = start_index;
        for (size_t i = 0; i < node_number; i++)
        {
    //%
            std::cout <<  i << std::endl;
    //%
            if (counter == NULL)
            {
                std::cout << "last index is " << i << std::endl;
                return counter;
            }
            counter = counter->link;
        }
        return counter;
    }

    void List::addNode(int data_)
    {
        NodePtr n = new Node;
        n->data = data_;
        n->link = NULL;

        if (head != NULL)
        {
            curr = head;
            while (curr != NULL)
                curr = curr->link;
            curr->link = n;
        }
        else
        {
            head = n;
            start_index = n;
        }
    }
```

main.cpp

```
  #include "Header.h"

    int main()
    {
        using namespace std;
        List one;
        one.addNode(1);
        one.addNode(2);
        one.addNode(3);
        //cout << (*one.head).data << endl;
        //cout << one.getPointer(1)->data << endl;
        cin.get();
    }
```

Comment: That error means you're dereferencing a NULL pointer. Use a debugger to see exactly where it's occurring. Also, turn up your compiler warnings.

Comment: Use the Visual Studio debugger and single step through *all* of your code.  Look at the link fields.  This should help you faster than asking for help on StackOverflow.

Comment: @Borgleader:  See OP's tag "visual-studio".  This is why I suggested the Visual Studio debugger.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After the loop

```
while (curr != NULL)
    curr = curr->link;
```

`curr` will be `NULL` (think about this until you realise why it is true).

Thus, the line

```
curr->link = n;
```

where you dereference the null pointer is invalid.

You want

```
while (curr->link != NULL)
    curr = curr->link;
```